# Quicksort Python

Tags: python, quicksort

I just simply don't know where it goes wrong with my code. I'm trying to use Quicksort method to sort an array in ascending order, doesn't seem to work.

```
def quicksort(array, left, right):
    if left < right: 
        pivot = partition(array, left, right)
        quicksort(array, left, pivot - 1)
        quicksort(array, pivot + 1, right)
        return array

def partition(array, left, right): #left and right are indices
    #pick the pivot as the middle element
    pivot = array[round((left + right)/2)]
    while left < right:
        while array[left] < pivot:
            left += 1
        while array[right] > pivot:
            right -= 1
    if left < right:
        # swap the 2 elements
        array[left], array[right] = array[right], array[left]
        left += 1
        right -= 1

    # swap the pivot and the last element (where the 2 pointers meet each other)
    array[left], array[array.index(pivot)] = array[array.index(pivot)], array[left]
    return left
```

so when

```
print(quicksort([4, 6, 8, 1, 3], 0, 4))
```

the result is

```
[3, 4, 6, 1, 8]
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Your code doesn't actually run, and if you fix the obvious errors it just gets into an infinite loop. But I suspect your `if left < right` should be `if array[left] < array[right]`.

Comment: could you explain what is your aim with this code ? what is the expected result ?

Comment: I wanna use the Quick Sort method to sort an array, but it doesn't work @Dadep

Comment: @DanielRoseman it doesn't matter because if array[left] < the pivot and array[right] > the pivot then it is obvious that array[left] < array[right] no?

Answer (score 0):

it is in your partition function,  This is not exactly the same partition algorithm but it works and I couldn't find the one you were using.

```
def partition(array, l, r): #left and right are indices
    #pick the pivot as the middle element
    m = round((l + r)/2)
    array[l], array[m] = array[m], array[l]
    pivot = array[l]
    #place holders
    i = l + 1
    j = r
    while  i <= j:
        while array[j] > pivot:  #do while array[j] is greater than pivot  
            j = j - 1
        while i <= j and array[i] < pivot: #do while array[i] is less than pivot  
            i += 1 
        if i <= j:
            array[i], array[j] = array[j], array[i]
            i += 1
            j -= 1

    array[l], array[j] = array[j], array[l] # swap the pivot and last elements
    return j
```

If you need to use the algorithm you tried post the psuedo code and it will help no what logic your trying to follow
  (sorry if this is a comment I don't have the reputation to make them)

Final answer:
again

```
def partition(array, l, r): #left and right are indices
    #pick the pivot as the middle element
    m = round((l + r)/2)'
    array[l], array[m] = array[m], array[l] #move pivot to right side
    pivot = array[l]
    #place holders
    i = l + 1
    j = r
    while  i <= j:
        while array[j] > pivot:  #do while array[j] is greater than pivot  
            j = j - 1
        while i <= j and array[i] < pivot: #do while array[i] is less than pivot  
            i += 1 
        if i <= j:
            array[i], array[j] = array[j], array[i]
            i += 1
            j -= 1

    array[l], array[j] = array[j], array[l] # if swap the pivot and last element
    return j return partition
```

Comment: Sorry but I dont understand your code. Could you pls add some comments? The way I see it is that the pivot is not the middle element of the array.

Comment: Sorry I left your old comment in. Most of these don't start in the middle of the array Is there a reason you need to?

Comment: There's not, but if you start with the very first element, wouldn't `i = l - 1` be out of the array? I read somewhere that starting at the middle of the array avoids worst-case scenario but doesn't matter to me now.

Comment: I just edited the code with comments. the way it works the i-1 becomes i before it is used.  This worked for me on a 10 element array.  I'll look a little bit to see if I can find the center based algorithm